# What is difference between CreateResponse() and CreateErrorResponse()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've written an endpoint and it's return type is HttpResponseMessage. Now I'm confusing about to create a response- we can use either CreateResponse() or CreateErrorResponse() to create a response, both are returning HttpResponseMessage. When we use CreateResponse() and when CreateErrorResponse()?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`CreateResponse`***

[CreateResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is a Helper method that performs content negotiation and creates a HttpResponseMessage with an instance of System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1 as the content and OK as the status code if a formatter can be found. If no formatter is found, this method returns a response with status 406 NotAcceptable.

***`CreateErrorResponse`***

[CreateErrorResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2) also a Helper method that creates a HttpResponseMessage representing an error with an instance of System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1 wrapping an HttpError for model state modelState. If no formatter is found, this method returns a response with status 406 NotAcceptable

***`When to Use:`***

Usually when your request would have successful response then you have to use `CreateResponse`with http status code. on the other hand if your request encounters a server side exception its good to handle with `CreateErrorResponse` with relevant error code.

Please refer to [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Hope that would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the docs, you will see, that `CreateResponse` returns an Ok() result, while `CreateErrorResponse` returns an exception, modelstate error or any other form of error, that your code procudes.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2